# SSRS- Hide Tablix based on another Tablix Value

Tags: .net, variables, reporting-services, dataset, query-string

I am kind of new to the SSRS programming and I've come across a challenge that I cannot find an answer to. We are in the process securing our SSRS site and I've been successful thus far, but I am trying to do the following:

When a user logs in, we have their UserID. I have a table that houses UserID's and their "Role" Name. What I want to do is if the logged in user's ID does not appear in the list (List of specific roles") then do not return any data. Either Hide the Tablix or display a message saying they are not authorized.

So far I have my main report (`DataSet1`) and I have my lookup table (`DataSet2`). I have the following expression on the Main report under visibility.

```
=IIF(First(Fields!LoginNm.Value, "DataSet2") = Parameters!UserID.Value,False,True)
```

The problem is this will work if the very first user ID in the list is the person logged in, but anything after that it will not work properly. I tried removing `First` but then I just get an error.

Can anyone help me figure out how to hide a table with the values from another table?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Lookup` instead:

```
=IIF(Lookup(Parameters!UserID.Value, Fields!LoginNm.Value, Fields!LoginNm.Value, "DataSet2") = Parameters!UserID.Value, False, True)
```

The `Lookup` function is available in SSRS 2008 R2 and beyond.

Note that the user Id is also available in the global variable `User!UserID`.